# Anonymous event

Tags: c#, java, xamarin.android

I am stuck with writing a C# Mono for Android equivalent of following Java event handler code:

```
public class Player extends ListActivity
{
    private ImageView list;//basically this is a buttona

    private void SetupButtonListeners()
    {
        list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                  //do stuff
             }
        });
    }
    /*
       more stuff here
    */
}
```

API REF: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.Button

Comment: What C# type corresponds to ImageView class? Or how setOnClickListener is defined? (Note: I've removed thankyou notes, upvoting good answers and adding actionable question is better use of space)

Comment: there is `Android.Widget.ImageView` class in C# Android Mono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no anonymous interface implementations in C# which is what you need according to [documentaton](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.View.SetOnClickListener%28Android.Views.View%2bIOnClickListener%29):

```
public virtual void SetOnClickListener (View.IOnClickListener l)
```

Unless there is some helper classes already you need to write class that implements this interface and pass it in. If you can't find existing one you should be able to create helper function that creates class and takes delegate as implementation of OnClick method.

Answer (score 4):

While you can set an a click listener as shown in the other answer, similar to how it's done in Java, that's not the preferred way to do things in Mono for Android. Since C# doesn't have anonymous class definitions, Mono for Android actually translates these listener interfaces into events, which leads to a much nicer API. For example, in this case you can use the [`Click`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E%3aAndroid.Views.View.Click) event that is present on any `View` class:

```
ListView list;

list.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                      {
                          // do stuff
                      };
```